# Regression specification choices

Tags: regression

I am studying a population of individuals who all begin with a measureable score of interest (ranging from -2 to 2) [call it "old"], then they all undergo a change to a new score (also ranging from -2 to 2) ["new"]. Thus all the variation is in the change (which can be positive or negative), and there are also a variety of predictors that help to explain variation in the amount of change.

My initial model is simply:

```
change = a + bx + e
```

where x is my vector of predictors.

But now I'm concerned that some of these predictors could be correlated with the baseline (old) score. Is this, then, a better specification?

```
change = a + bx + old +  e
```

Or perhaps

```
new = a + bx + old + e
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, version 1 is not acceptable. The second or third options (as long as `old` has a coefficient that will be estimated) are both OK, and in fact equivalent with respect to estimates for `a` and `b`. This can be seen if you replace `change` with `new-old` in the second equation, and solve it for `new`. All that happens is that the coefficient of `old` is increased by 1 as compared to the third equation. Other statistics such as R^2 will change, of course, as they are decomposing a different variability.

Note, however, that you have a different problem as well. If your scores are restricted to a -2 to 2 range, somebody with `old=-2` cannot possibly get worse, and similarly for `old=2` you can't get any better. Such a range restriction is usually not modeled well by a linear regression.

Answer (score 2):

A few references that you might find useful:

- Edwards (2001) has a nice article called [Ten Difference Score Myths](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Ten-Difference-Score-Myths-Edwards/d65459d88369b3d7ec0352f589c07b9d85993bd1).
- I have a [post with some general points on change scores](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2009/09/difference-scores-are-they-okay-to-use.html).

Comment: Your blog is chock full of useful nuggets; thanks!